# owssvr.dll copied by .iqy does work for one list, but not for another

Tags: rpc, sharepoint-online

I already tried to find something for this specific problem, but did not found anything...

I want to connect Sharepoint to QlikView. I did this two time before with two other lists. I retried this method, to make sure, I did everything correct, which I did.

I get my URL for the request from sharepoint via an .iqy. This normally works just fine. Now I have a new list and wanted to do the same thing. The Excel connection via .iqy works fine, as usual. But if I put in the url into any browser, I get an "This site is temporarily not available" instead of the usual xml answer. The URL is perfectly fine, compared with the working ones...

The only difference I can make out is, that the two working lists are in another site collection (I hope that is the right term).

I tried looking for any setting or features which are configured differently, but I did not find a thing and if the .iqy can connect via excel, I do not see, why it should not work with any other tool...

Does anyone have a clue, what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, the Problem is a field type. You cannot export Persons like this, at least in our setup.